# How to add Scroll to jDesktopPane

Tags: java, swing

I am a beginner and creating a java desktop application in MDI format and so have used the JDesktopPane and Internal Frames. I am using NetBeans Drag and Drop mainly for this. Now i have a requirement to design a page that could have a property to scroll. I need to know how can i work upon this.

I have been through the following code but got no positive result. [Link for the referal](https://github.com/dukke/swing-desktopScrollPane)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The problem may be is.... the code is as if design a layout through the hard code and not the netbeans drag and drop.

Comment: You need to post your code **in the question** not as an offsite link (because of possible linkrot in the future, if this happens your question has no value). In addition people here may not know how to use github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got a solution. it may not be a proper solution but yes if i tried to add scrollpane as a parent to Desktop Pane it worked.

Comment: It is not the long term solution. What if you don't want whole window to be in JScrollPane?

Answer (score 1):

Add all components to **panel**
and set view port

scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);

**Example:**

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(button1);//add some other componets that are already initialized
....
scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: How can i get it done as i am doing drag and drop of components in NetBeans

Comment: Aren't the components dynamic?? And please use Eclipse. Using NetBeans is faster though for certain applications

Comment: This is my first Desktop Application, so was not much mature in coding dynamic i will take care of the things in future, but now wat's the solution

Comment: Not quite sure about it. But try to set the viewport for the scrollPane. May be rightClicking and going to source would do fine.

Comment: for which component i need to change the viewPort

Comment: For JScrollPane Object of course :-). Hope you can find a solution. Good Luck. I would help but I don't have Netbeans right now

Comment: That's OK. Thanks for your valuable time and help